# How to prevent multiple notifications rendering on view with RenderAction

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have following scenario.
I'm setting up `INotifier` notification in controller and after that i'm redirecting to other action. On the view where i'm redirecting i have some  `Html.RenderAction` helpers. 
Every time when action is rendered fires `NotifyFilter.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)` and every method call the message set to `tempData[TempDataMessages]` (where notification message is saved by `NotifyFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)` is added new message entry.

My controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("SomeAction")]
public ActionResult SomeActionPost()
{
  _notifier.Information(T("Important information"));
  return RedirectToAction("OtherAction", "MyController");
}

public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
  return View();
}
```

And the view:

```
<div>
 @{ Html.RenderAction("ActionOne", "MyController");}
 @{ Html.RenderAction("ActionTwo", "MyController");}
</div>
```

So notification is tripled (once by `ActionResult OtherAction`, once by `ActionResult ActionOne` and once by `ActionResult ActionTwo`.
Anybody knows how to prevent additional notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no easy way of doing that. You can try adding your own action filter and clear the `TempData["messages"]` value at some point or do that from inside your parent view. Both solutions are workarounds, though, and equally messy.

Btw - `Html.RenderAction` should be used with caution. *Don't* use it unless you're perfectly sure what are the implications. It makes multiple actions being processed in a single request. This is very slow and will run you into problems (like the one you wrote about) sooner or later. Most of code out there assumes there is a one action fired during a request.

If you can handle things without it (which in most cases is possible), do it.